# --tags does not skip vars_prompt in ansible

Tags: ansible

When I run ansible-playbook --tags tag2, why does not it skip vars_prompt from tag1? Anyhow it skips debug msg from tag1. Please help. This is making me write 2 different playbooks.

```yaml
---
 - name: variable print using var
   hosts: all
   gather_facts: no
   tags: tag1

   vars_prompt:
     - name: ask_user
       prompt: enter your name
       private: no

   tasks:
     - debug:
         msg: "{{ ask_user}} works in ABC company"

 - hosts: all
   gather_facts: no
   tags: tag2

   tasks:
     - name: normal message
       debug:
         msg: "This is 2nd tag"
```

Answer (score 4):

Q: **"*--tags does not skip vars_prompt in Ansible*"**

A: *vars_prompt* is not a task and therefore can't be skipped. Quoting from [Tags](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#tags)

> Using tags to execute or skip selected **tasks** is a two-step process:

> 1. Add tags to your tasks, either individually or with tag inheritance from a block, play, role, or import.

> 2. Select or skip tags when you run your playbook.

---

If you want to skip the prompting for a variable use [pause](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#ansible-builtin-pause-pause-playbook-execution) instead of *vars_prompt*. For example, the playbook below does what you want

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tags: tag1
  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: Enter your name
        echo: true
      register: result
    - set_fact:
        ask_user: "{{ result.user_input }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ask_user }} works in ABC company"

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tags: tag2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: This is tag2
```